# C# Fix the size of picture box even when the size of the windows is changed

Tags: c#, winforms

May I know how do we fixed the size of the picture box? Because for now, everytime I drag to change the winform size, the size of the picture box on it will change too.

Comment: Is this WPF, WinForms, Silverlight, WinRT? How is the `PictureBox` defined?

Comment: I think its winform , check `change the winform size`, I have just edited the tag as well

Comment: Check did you set Anchor property to Right/Bottom ?

Answer (score 3):

You have set your anchor property of your PictureBox to:

```
Top, Bottom, Left, Right
```

You may set it to

```
Top, Left
```

Look in the properties for the picture box, Currently it will be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of your `PictureBox` and make sure the `Dock` property is set to `None`;

Use the `Anchor` property to define how a control is automatically resized as its parent control is resized:

> ***[`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)***: Gets or sets the edges of the container to which a control is bound and determines how a control is resized with its parent.

Comment: And make sure the Dock property is set to None